# Get single value from a single row of a Joomla database query result

Tags: php, joomla, resultset

I am trying to pull the value from the `loadResultArray` call below:

```
$query = 'SELECT cb_featuredvideo FROM #__comprofiler WHERE user_id = '.$id.'';

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);
$youtube = $db->loadResultArray();
$link = $youtube[0];
// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects.
$results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

The problem is when I check the value for `$link` it is coming up as null.  If I print the array from `$results` I get the expected output:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [cb_featuredvideo] => http://youtu.be/ytJCZnG3k9k ) )
```

Why isn't the `$link` value showing the youtube link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about `loadResult()` ?

According to http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase :

**Use loadResult() when you expect just a single value back from your database query.**

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('field_name');
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__my_table'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('some_name')." = ".$db->quote($some_value));

$db->setQuery($query);
$result = $db->loadResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$youtube = $db->loadObjectList();
```

instead of

```
$youtube = $db->loadResultArray();
```

For more details see http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Thank you, but I am trying to set the `$link` value as the youtube link.  By setting the `$youtube = $db->loadObjectList();` I am still getting the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $results is an array of objects. So you might want to try

```
$link = $results[0]->cb_featuredvideo;
```